# What are the recommended Semantic Web reasoners for developers?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, reasoning, pellet

I'm looking for Semantic Web reasoners that can be applied to large datasets (Linked Data). I've seen several options and Pellet seems to be a good choice, but it last release was in 2013 and it has some problems with the last version of Java. Does anyone know some other good option considering community support, documentation, programming languages supported etc.?

Comment: It seems that most of the OWL-based reasoning efforts have gone dormant, so 2013 is fairly current.  That's just a personal observation that others may be able to update.  Another observation is that SPARQL is getting more uptake and addresses a much broader set of use cases.

Comment: Some of the reasoners have also gone proprietary.  For instance, I think that the folks associated with Pellet are now working on Stardog, a triple store with inference capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what you want the reasoner to do. [Hermit](http://www.hermit-reasoner.com/) is a good reasoner for classification but I would not use it in the scenario you describe. Also you have to ask yourself about what sort of reasoning features the datasets you mention have. What sort of linked data is it? Is there (if any) logical rules that apply to them?

I don't know if it works for you, but you can consider using a triplestore such as Stardog or Virtuoso which have reasoning capabilities and can manage large datasets.